# how to break up lines of codes AND comments in VB.NET 2010?

Tags: vb.net, comments

everytime i try the space then underscore + enter it doesnt work and it lights up red

edit - like for example this is a comment:

'you must add such and such to this variable and then you must declare it'

say i have that for a comment and i want to break the comment after variable. when i do this

'you must add such and such to this variable _

and then you must declare it'

it gives me an error

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you restate it?

Comment: Are you asking about line wrapping? Example:       ' Some code _ (then on next line)                                                                                                                                           Some more code'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underscore at the end of the line trick doesn't work for comments. The underscores are treated as part of the comment.

To create a bunch of single line comments at once, select the lines you want to comment out and press `CTRL+K` then `CTRL+C`

Comment: well how do you break up comments then?

Comment: @goku8000 You create several single line comments.

Answer (score 1):

A line continuation consists of at least one white-space character that immediately precedes a single underscore character as the last character (other than white space) in a text line.

[Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711641%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Doesn't apply to comments though; if you want multiple comment lines simply start a new comment for each subsequent line.